# TinyMCE Browser Spell Check

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

I am using TinyMCE, and I am using the browser's built in spell checker. The issue that I am having, and I don't know if I have any control over is the spell checker:

- Doesn't replace all words after `right click -> select new word`

  - It will replace some words in the document
  - Some words it do not change at all and the browser keeps saying the word is spelt wrong. To fix the error you need to manually change the spelling.
- Doesn't always show that there is an error the the text

Here is how I am configuring the editor:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "#savedstory",
    theme: "modern",
    height: 450,
    browser_spellcheck: true,
    gecko_spellcheck: true,
    plugins: [
        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
        "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table directionality",
        "emoticons template paste textcolor"
    ],
    toolbar1: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic underline | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image media",
    toolbar2: "print preview fullscreen | cut copy paste | removeformat"
});
```

Does anyone have any suggestions to fix this? I am not looking for browser plugins or configurations either.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add the below code in your init

```
setup : function(ed) {
                ed.on('init', function(evt) {
                  ed.getBody().setAttribute('spellcheck', true);
                });
}
```

Comment: I don't have the code any more, so I have no idea if this will work

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn, I know it has been a while. Just posted, if that could help someonce else. Thanks.